# Downloading file with a specific substring from AWS S3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a python function to download csv files from AWS S3 Bucket. The folder I want to download from has a lot of csv files with various naming conventions and out of all those, I want to download files that contain a certain substring.

The files I want to download are named as:

- `BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-01.csv`
- `BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-02.csv`
- `BANK_NIFTY_5MINs_2020-01-03.csv`
  and so on.

I do not want to download all the csv files from the folder of 2020, just the csv files that have the substring. Can someone please help on how I can do that?

The below code is where I run the function but this does not download the data:

```
download_from_s3(s3_uri="s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/2020/BANK_NIFTY_5MINs*.csv", local_dir=os.path.join("2020Data"))
```

How can I specify the substring of the csv files I want to download?

Comment: The `download_from_s3()` method is not offered directly by boto3. Are you using a library of some sort to access S3? (eg Anaconda?)

Comment: Yes, I have a whole function written using boto3. "download_from_s3" is just the name of the function I've written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command in Amazon S3 to download objects via a wildcard. At some stage, your code would need to make an API call to S3 **with the *exact* name (Key) of the object** you want to download.

Therefore, your code would need to call `list_objects_v2()` to **obtain a listing of objects** in the S3 bucket. Then, you can **use string comparison logic in Python** to determine which objects you want to download, and call `download_file()` for each of them.